# Cannot add ::after pseudo-element to slotted element in shadow dom

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I was experimenting with Eric Bidelman's `<fancy-tabs>` shadow dom example: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom

And was trying to add Material Design styling to it, which would require adding an :after pseudo element to the tabs.

After some experimentation I found that the internal styles for applying pseudo elements do appear to work when using Polymer, but not when using vanilla JS...

Polymer example:
https://jsbin.com/maqaze/edit?html,output

Vanilla JS example:

In this second example, applying the :after pseudo element does not work within the shadow dom `<style>` it apparently needs to be set externally.

https://jsbin.com/toxalu/edit?html,output

So my question is, how should you go about adding a pseudo element to a slotted / light dom element, without needing to use external styles?

(have tried these examples on Chrome and Safari)

Comment: The major point of shadow DOM is to separate CSS styles from the _outside_. By doing what you are asking, you would actually be counter-productive. If you have light-DOM elements inside shadow DOM, you should style them outside the shadow DOM.

Comment: The spec allows you to modify the style for 'distributed' nodes (i.e. user contributed light-dom that is slotted into the element's shadow tree) https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#stylinglightdom The question I'm asking is whether it also allows you to modify the CSS pseudo elements properties :after and :before.  Perhaps this is considered as 'adding boxes' to the light dom and is as such disallowed. I was thrown by the fact that it does work in the Polymer example given above, but perhaps that is an issue with that implementation itself?

Answer (score 1):

If it seems to work in Polymer it's due to the fact that Polymer 1.0 doesn't really use native `::slotted` pseudo-elements.

In fact Polymer uses native Shadow DOM "v0" and [converts `::slotted` to `::content`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3976). You can see it in the Dev Tools.

As you have noted you can add `::after` pseudo-elements from the outside.

I suppose pseudo-elements are considered as *complex selectors* and therefore are not supported within `::slotted()`.

Comment: Thanks. I did notice the `::content` and `::slotted` conversions and was wondering what was going on!

Comment: Slotted can actually be used with pseudo-elements like `::after` (e.g. `::slotted(input)::after`), [discussion](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/655#issuecomment-324446879)